# Can RVM, rbenv and Homebrew create problems in a working Ruby on Rails env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew, rbenv

I installed Ruby and Rails couple of months ago, and I do not remember if i used Homebrew or RVM or rbenv.

Presently I have all the three installed on my Mac. I did not touch the system installed Ruby.

Is there anything I need to worry about with these three things present on my system? Is there a chance that they may mess up my perfectly working Ruby and Rails environment?

Which one should I keep or can I keep all three?

If I need to remove any or all, can anyone also help me in removing everything, RVM, rbenv, Homebrew, Ruby and Rails and make a clean installation?

Comment: RVM and rbenv are mutually exclusive; Pick one or the other. It's possible to have them both installed without conflicts, however the odds go way up that they'll get in the way of each other the more you rely on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely want to keep Homebrew and either RVM or rbenv.

Once you decide which Ruby version manager you would like to use (rbenv or RVM) then follow the instructions to uninstall one of them, either `brew uninstall rbenv` assuming you installed rbenv with Homebrew, or `rvm implode`.

From there you should be good if you didn't touch the system Ruby.

Comment: It'd be good to check the ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc and ~/.profile files to make sure the associated commands there are intact and/or removed.

Comment: I use RVM because that is what is being used on my project.  That said the consensus seems to be that RBENV is more robust but a bit harder to learn initially than RVM.  RVM is super easy but sometimes you have to install fresh gemsets because it gets buggy.